# What is wrong in my this Javascript code for writing a Fibonacci series?

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

Fibonacci series code goes here

```js
function fibonnica(g) {
  var result, n;
  if (g == 1) {
    return g; //if enterd no is 1 then 1 that is very apparent
  } else {
    result = g; //7
    n = g - 1; //6
    while (n > 0) {
      result *= n ///7*6 second time 7*5 and so on..
      n = n - 1; //n=5
    }
    return result;
  }
}
console.log(fibonnica(7)); //why 7  is the output
```

please only tell the error not the solution i want to push myself

Comment: you have `while(n<0){`  typo I guess!

Comment: Actually this is not Fibonacci series rather than factorial calculation

Comment: Sorry, but it was not working in the console of the other webpage I don't know why.

Comment: But now it works

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch the condition to check greater number, than smaller numbers.

```
while (n > 0) {
//       ^
```

```js
function fibonnica(g) {
    var result, n;
    if (g == 1) {
        return g;
    } else {
        result = g;
        n = g - 1;
        while (n > 0) {
            result *= n;
            n = n - 1;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
console.log(fibonnica(7)); // 5040
```

Comment: the typo was in the post for less than 20 sec. Do we edit the question to make the answer valid as the typo does not exist anymore, then web flag it as off topics because of typo . Or we flag it with can't reproduce. As they are both the same flag I've already casted mine

Comment: @PierreLebon, i would go for typo, becuase the first version was with typo, with changed compariosn, it not anymore a question at all.

Comment: Both flag are in the same option. I guess, We can't fail.